ADF Concat function re-escapes double quotes in string variables
Creating a JSON body for a Web activity fails when the Concat function re-escapes double quotes in string values.  If I have a string variable when an array of JSON:
[ { "name": "gary" }, { "name": "frank" } ]

then that variable is with the Concat function added to a valid JSON:
@concat('{ "value:" ', variables('Array Values'), '}')

all the double quotes from the Array Values string are re-escaped which doesn't play nicely with a subsequent Web activity.  Wrapping the resulting string from the Concat function inside a Json function followed by a String function has no effect since the Concat already re-escaped the double quotes.

in your web activity accessit with @json()

In ADF when you put Json or array in String variable it will escape " by default to resolve it you need to USE @json function directly in body of web activity.

Use @json function to convert string to Json in appropriate format directly into web activity body.

It will pass the correct Json to web activity input as below:


Problem in my case was that I wasn't adding JSON to the array (i.e. @json(...)) so the array had strings not JSON.  But your answer is correct on what the JSON could de-escape.
